# Why is dplyr group_by and summarize not working?

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the mean for each sub-dataset in my dataset, but my output just gives me the mean for the whole dataset for each sub-dataset. I think it might be an issue with the way my dataset is structured: the data consists of x and y observations for **13 sub-datasets** that have the following names:`dino`, `away`, `h_lines`, `v_lines`, `x_shape`, `star`, `high_lines`, `dots`, `circle`, `bullseye`, `slant_up`, `slant_down`, `wide_lines`. The sub-dataset names are listed in a column called "dataset" (see example picture below).

[dataset snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2gil.png)

I'm using the dplyr functions group_by() and summarize(). I've seen so many examples where this works, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

This is what I've tried

```
dinodata%>%
  dplyr::group_by(dataset)%>%
  dplyr::summarize(mean_x = mean(x),
            mean_y = mean(y),
            sd_x = sd(x),
            sd_y = sd(y),
            correlation = cor(x,y)
            )
```

and this is the output

```
# A tibble: 13 x 6
   dataset    mean_x mean_y  sd_x  sd_y correlation
   <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 away         54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0641
 2 bullseye     54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0686
 3 circle       54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0683
 4 dino         54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0645
 5 dots         54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0603
 6 h_lines      54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0617
 7 high_lines   54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0685
 8 slant_down   54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0690
 9 slant_up     54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0686
10 star         54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0630
11 v_lines      54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0694
12 wide_lines   54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0666
13 x_shape      54.3   47.8  16.8  26.9     -0.0656
```

The means and standard deviations are calculating the same as if I did mean(dinodata$x) and sd(dinodata$x) which is not what I want. I want the mean for each sub-dataset for x and y, etc.

Comment: You may need to double check your data. Your code works fine on my machine, providing subgroup results with `mtcars` data.

Comment: Your code is ok, I think this behaviour (same mean, std) is done on purpose, is this your dataframe? https://www.autodeskresearch.com/publications/samestats

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: @fmarm yes, that's the dataframe- probably can be found elsewhere by searching "datasaurus"

Comment: PLOT TWIST: the summary statistics are supposed to be the exact same for all groups... my code is working I was just fooled by the question (check out the autodesk article linked above)